# Swapping values in array C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    swap(a[i], a[size - i - 1]);
}
```

It looks correct.. and it is because I have used it in other languages, but on C++ it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What's the type of `a`?

Comment: The resulting array would be the same: because you swap the first half of the array and then swap the second half - resulting in no changes.

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried stepping through this program? Because at a glance, it doesn't look like it would work.

Like, for the following input, you'd get the following results:

```
a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
i == 0: a = {4, 1, 2, 3, 0};
i == 1: a = {4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
i == 2: a = {4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
i == 3: a = {4, 1, 2, 3, 0};
i == 4: a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

See what's happening? The numbers are getting swapped, and then swapped again.

Cutting it off half-way should fix the problem.

```
for (i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
{
    swap(a[i], a[size - i - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
{
    swap(a[i], a[size - i - 1]);
}
```

Since you will swap each item twice if you go `i < size`

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using c++ you can use some awesome `c++` features, like [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

```
std::reverse(&a[0], &a[0] + size);
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/in3J2q)

Comment: if `a` is a pointer or a static array, `&a[0]` can be replaced with `a`: `std::reverse(a, a + size);` I assume it is a pointer since `size` exists. In which case, `std::vector` is better to use then managing a dynamic array manually. You can use `begin()` and `end()` to iterate a vector: `std::reverse(a.begin(), a.end());`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, i assumed the same because of `size`, with `&a[0]` i prefer this because it is clear that you are referencing the start, then the start plus size, it compiles the same anyway right?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that feature but I want to do it in this way. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap). It swaps 2 values in an array using the appropriate iterators:

```
std::iter_swap(std::begin(a) + i, std::end(a) - i - 1);
```

Comment: Note that `std::begin()` and `std:end()` require C++11. For earlier versions, go back to using pointers: `std::iter_swap(&a[i], &a[size - i - 1]);`